# Indefinite as sumand

Tags: functions, piecewise-continuity

My question is based on some questions about piecewise functions. The problem is when I "sum" two piecewise functions that don't share any interval. When I draw the graphic of this function in geogebra, for example, it does not exist. Because $ f(x) $ is a real number, then I thought that the problem was that adding some $ x $ real number with a number that does not exists, the sum is indeterminate. I just want to confirm that.

We got a function $f(x)=1$ for $0\leq x\leq1$ and $f(x)=2$ for $1<x\leq2$.
We got also a function $g(x)=f(2x)$
We got also a function $h(x)=f(x-2)$
And finally we got $k(x)=g(x)=h(x)$, which graphic does not exists.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Formally, you can sum two functions only when they share the same domain and codomain. Since your $f:[0,2]\to\mathbb{R}$ is only defined for $0\leq x\leq 2$, it is easy to see that, in the best scenario (that is, the greatest domain possible), $\text{Dom}(g)=[0,1]$ and $\text{Dom}(h)=[2,4]$. So, what happens with $k(x)=g(x)+h(x)$? Well, $g$ and $h$ have different domains so it is undefined and, therefore, it won't have any graph. However, not only that... If we redefined the sum of two real functions $f_1:D_1\to\mathbb{R}$ and $f_2:D_2\to\mathbb{R}$ as $(f_1+f_2):D_1\cap D_2\to\mathbb{R}; (f_1+f_2)(x)=f_1(x)+f_2(x)$, $k(x)=g(x)+h(x)$ would be well defined but, since now $\text{Dom}(k)=\text{Dom}(f+g)=\text{Dom}(f)\cap\text{Dom}(g)=\emptyset$, it will simply be the empty function and, thus, it will have empty graph.

Comment: Okey, got it. But that means that I did not learn some concepts during pre-calculus. Which book do you recommend me to start reviewing from algebra up to differential calculus with every single concept?